# How do I iterate over a hashtable in F#?

Tags: f#, hashtable

```
let dic = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
dic
|> Seq.filter( fun k -> k.Contains("COMNTOOLS"))
```

fails to compile. 
I've tried using `Array.filter, Seq.filter, List.filter`
I've tried getting just the `dic.Keys` to iterate over but F# doesn't seem to want me to coerce a `KeyCollection` into an `IEnumerable`.

I've tried upcasting the hashtable into an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

How do I walk the hashtable that is returned from `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` ?

Comment: You should specify the actual error, although I suspect it has to do with `k.Contains`. `k` is a KeyValuePari<,> so `Contains` doesn't exist

Comment: When I typed it in before adding more detail and removing the actual error without noticing, it was: *Cannot execute text selection: The type `IDictionary` is not compatible with the type `seq<'a>`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` returns a non-generic `IDictionary` and it stores key/value pairs in `DictionaryEntry`, you have to use `Seq.cast` first:

```
let dic = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()

dic
|> Seq.cast<DictionaryEntry>
|> Seq.filter(fun entry -> entry.Key.ToString().Contains("COMNTOOLS"))
```

See the relevant docs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary(v=vs.110).aspx. Notice that `entry.Key` is of type `obj`, so one has to convert to string before checking string containment.

Instead of using high-order functions, sequence expression might be handy:

```
let dic = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
seq {
    for entry in Seq.cast<DictionaryEntry> dic ->
        (string entry.Key), (string entry.Value)
}
|> Seq.filter(fun (k, _) -> k.Contains("COMNTOOLS"))
```

Answer (score 0):

F# Seq can only operate with `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<_>`. `System.IDictionary` returned by `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables` is not generic but it implements non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable` and not `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<_>`. `System.Collections.IEnumerable` does not contain type information and allows enumeration of the collection of boxed types i.e. instances of `System.Object`.
Anyway `System.IDictionary` can be enumerated as collection of `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` objects so you can simply call `Seq.cast` on it. It will give you access to `Key` and `Value` properties, yet still boxed as objects, so you should unbox them too.

```
let dic = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
dic
|> Seq.cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>
|> Seq.filter( fun k -> (k.Key :?> string).Contains("COMNTOOLS"))
```

Alternatively you can use the following function

```
let asStringPairSeq (d : System.Collections.IDictionary) : seq<string * string> =
    Seq.cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry> d
    |> Seq.map (fun kv -> kv.Key :?> string, kv.Value :?> string)

System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
|> asStringPairSeq
|> Seq.filter (fun (k,v) -> k.Contains("COMNTOOLS"))
```

Comment: First code block doesn't compile: *The type `DictionaryEntry` does not have any proper subtypes and cannot be used as the source of a type test or runtime coercion.* Second block doesn't compile as there doesn't seem to be a `System.Collections.Dictionary`, and gives the additional error: *The type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.seq<_>' expects 1 type argument(s) but is given 2* probably should be `string*string`.